# Apache does not have the permission to copy files from a mounted directory

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, sshfs

My application on the server wants to copy a file from a remote directory mounted by sshfs to a local directory. The application code:

```
shutil.copy('/data/somdir/somefile.txt','/var/www/App/localfolder' )
```

The permissions of /data is as follows:

```
drwxrwxrwx   1   1027 root  4096 May  6 10:16 data
```

So every user(including Apache) should able to access the folder, but in the logfile I get:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

**Some edits and updates on my question:**

I set allow_other when mounting via SSHFS, and all the directories along the path to the source file have permissions of at least 755.So any use has read access to it.

Comment: How about the permissions of files inside `/data`?

Comment: first of all, are you copying whole folder `/data` ?

Comment: no, jsut some specific files in /data/somedir. but all these folders have r+x permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mount with option `allow_other`.

If you rely on these permissions being *enforced*, add the option `default_permissions`.

Comment: default_permissions saved me.